# php regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Need help with regular expressions.

I have an html form to accept input for a license plate, birthday, and social insurance number.  I have a php script to read in the input using the `preg_match()` function. I cant seem to get these 3 `preg_match` functions to work with the examples posted below.

**Car license plate**: format `LLLDDD` or `DDDLLL` (`L`=letter; `D`=digit), there may be zero or one space between the letters and digits.

All of these are valid:

1. ABC123
2. 123ABC
3. ABC 123
4. 123 ABC

**Birthdate**: format `MMM­DD­YYYY`, `MMM` are three letters; `DD` and `YYYY` are numbers.

All of these are valid:

1. JAN-01-2002
2. MAY-30-1933

**Social Insurance Number**: 9 digits; may have zero or more spaces after each set of three

All of these are valid:

1. 111222333
2. `111 222         333`
3. `111       22233`

PHP script: lab11.php

```
<?php
    // Get license plate, birthday and 
    // social insurance number entered from lab11.html form

    $licensePlate = $_POST['licensePlate'];
    $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
    $socialInsuranceNumber = $_POST['socialInsuranceNumber'];

echo "<br>";
    // Validate regular expression for license plate entered
    if (preg_match("/^(\([\d]{3}\)|[\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?([\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?[\d]{3}(-|\s*)?[\d]{4}$/", $licensePlate)) 
    {
        echo "The license plate you entered is " . $licensePlate . ".";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "The license plate you entered is incorrect.";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    // Validate regular expression for birthday entered  
    if (preg_match("/^(\([\d]{3}\)|[\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?([\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?[\d]{3}(-|\s*)?[\d]{4}$/", $birthday)) 
    {
        echo "Your birthday is " . $birthday . ".";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Your birthday is incorrect.";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    // Validate regular expression for social insurance number entered   
    if (preg_match("/^(\([\d]{3}\)|[\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?([\d]{3})?(-|\s*)?[\d]{3}(-|\s*)?[\d]{3}$/", $socialInsuranceNumber))
    {
        echo "The social insurance number you entered was " . $socialInsuranceNumber . ".";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "The social insurance number you entered is incorrect.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why did you use the same regex for all three inputs? Did you write that regex? Doesn't seem like you'd ever want `()`s in your inputs.. Here's the license plates, `^([A-Z]\s?){3}(\d\s?){3}|(\d\s?){3}([A-Z]\s?){3}$`. Metacharacters dont need to be in character classes and `\d` is a number, not letters.

Comment: I think birthday would look like his : `^(JAN|FEV|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-\d{2}-\d{4}$`

Comment: last thing i need help with is how to get more than 1 whitespace displayed between each grouping of 3 digits for the social insurance number. For example if you enter :"111     333222" i want it to display like that instead, it displays like this: "111 333222"

Answer (score 1):

For Car license plate, use the following:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3}\s*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{3}\s*[a-zA-Z]{3}$/", $licensePlate))
```

For Birthdate, use the following:

```
if (preg_match("/^(?i)(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-\d{2}-\d{4}$/", $birthday))
```

For Social Insurance Number, use the following:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{3}\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3}$/", $socialInsuranceNumber))
```

.

Update:

If you want the Social Insurance Number to display whitespaces, you can use the `str_replace` fuction as the following:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{3}\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3}$/", $socialInsuranceNumber))
{
    $socialInsuranceNumber = str_replace(" ","&nbsp;", $socialInsuranceNumber);
    echo "The social insurance number you entered was " . $socialInsuranceNumber . ".";
}
```

Comment: still cannot get to display more than 1 whitespace displayed between each grouping of 3 digits for the social insurance number if that is what is entered by the user. For example, if you enter :"111      333222" i want it to display like that instead, it displays like this: "111 333222"

Comment: @user7123308 I updated the code to display whitespaces.

Comment: @Ibrahim No need for all of those `JAN|jan|FEB|feb...`, Using the `i` modifier will take care of letter case. Just a bit of a sidenote here ;-)

Comment: Yeah you are right, I though about that after posting my code.

Answer (score 1):

For the social security number you can remove all chars but 0-9 by using preg replace then check the string length is 9.

For the dates use the datetime object and use create from format

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

For the car plate. Use 2 regex one for letters first. One for letters last it will make maintainace easier too

Regex while it's possible to do all 3 it's not really the right tool